# How to call a method when user keep pressing a button?

Tags: iphone, xcode, button

I know how to call a method when a button pressed.

but, My problem is when a user keep pressing a button it has to call one method

-(void)keeppressed
{
}

where as it has to call another method called

-(void)justpressed
{
}

when user just taps the button

is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Write a method `x` actually conatining the code you want to run, which is called from both.

Comment: actually the keeppressing method should not call when tapping on that button. it should call when user keep pressing have any idea on this?

Comment: and we should not use touch events here..this is the issue.

Comment: But, obviously the function `keeppressed` does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

There is UIGestureRecognizer which can handle taps and long presses. If this doesn't work for you (only available sind 3.2 IIRC), you should start a timer after the press and call keeppressed if it hasn't been released in meantime (wire up the actions for press and release / cancel).